# The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, int

Tags: java, minecraft

I keep getting the error The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, int
on my code and I have no idea on what to do to fix it.
The error appears inside eclipse as well as on launch

Some help would be greatly appreciated :) Thanks!

```
  private boolean[] ctexture = new boolean[16]; 

  public boolean[] flipTopBottom = new boolean[16];

      this.ctexture[id] = connectedTexture;

  @SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
  public Icon getIcon(int par1, int par2)
  {
    if ((par1 <= 1) && (this.flipTopBottom[(par2 & 0xF)] != 0)  //The error occurs here// && ((this.icons[(par2 & 0xF)] instanceof IconConnectedTexture))) {
      return new IconConnectedTextureFlipped((IconConnectedTexture)this.icons[(par2 & 0xF)]);
    }
    return this.icons[(par2 & 0xF)];
  }


  @SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
  public void registerIcons(IconRegister par1IconRegister)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
      if ((this.texture[i] != null) && (this.texture[i] != "")) {
        if (this.ctexture[i] != 0) { //It also occurs here
          this.icons[i] = new IconConnectedTexture(par1IconRegister, this.texture[i]);
        } else {
          this.icons[i] = par1IconRegister.registerIcon(this.texture[i]);
        }
      }
```

Comment: list only that part of code..

Comment: Please also state what line the error occurs on (and list the particular part of your code)

Comment: Do you know what a boolean is, what an int is, and what != does?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have:

```
private boolean[] ctexture = new boolean[16];
```

Then you do:

```
if(this.ctexture[i] != 0)
        ↑              ↑
     boolean          int
```

In Java, you can't do that, 0 is an `int`, `this.ctexture[i]` is a `boolean`.

You should probably do:

```
if(this.ctexture[i]) //if true
```

<sup>You have invalid comparisons in other places too, please fix them as well</sup>

Comment: Okay, but if I set it to true, the icon shows, but the textures do not connect (That's the idea, for the textures to connect)

Comment: would errors like this be caused from deobfuscating code? Because i was using this code from another project to learn more complex methods and using the original produces no errors in the game, only when looked at in eclipse

Comment: @user3219869 Did that code contain the lines that caused the errors?

Comment: if (this.ctexture[i] != 0) { <--- from the original obfuscated file

Comment: @user3219869 That's wrong, unless `ctexture` is an array of `int`s there.

Comment: unless im forgetting code somewhere, but i dont think i can be bothered sifting through hundreds of lines of code looking for something that may be missing. also the whole project runs perfectly fine, even along side my own

Comment: holy god i am dumb, forgot to register the custom renderer under the client proxy.... :S     Anyway It WORKS! finally after 1.5 days of tinkering

Answer (score 0):

In some languages, the boolean type is closely related to int, so that comparing a boolean to 0 makes sense. In Java, they are totally distinct types. boolean can only be compared to other boolean expressions.

To test for a boolean being false, use `!this.ctexture[i]`. For true, simply use the boolean.

Answer (score 0):

`flipToBottom` is an array of booleans but you try to compare one entry (a boolean) to an integer.

```
if ((par1 <= 1) && (this.flipTopBottom[(par2 & 0xF)] != 0)
```

Something like

```
if ((par1 <= 1) && !this.flipTopBottom[(par2 & 0xF)])
```

Might be what you are after. (General convention is to not say `if (variable == true)` or `if (variable == false)`. use `if(variable)` or `if (!variable)` instead.